# Axis 1 : How to log Request and Response xml

Tags: java, xml, soap, axis

I am working on Axis1.4 and generated java clients from wsdl. 
I am looking for a good working example which shows how to log complete SOAP Request and Response. I did see couple of examples where handleRequest, handleResponse methods are used but I failed to understand how to make use/invoke these handlers from my java classes to capture request/response.

For an example, Here is how I am invoking a service and get the response. I am trying to understand on how to capture the full SOAP XML Request/Response in my code.

```
//locate service

FundEditorServiceImplServiceLocator locator = new FundEditorServiceImplServiceLocator();

FundEditorService service = locator.getFundEditorServiceImplPort();//invoke service 

FundInfo response = service.getFundInfo(fundInfoSpec);
```

Comment: This link has the complete implementation - https://developervisits.wordpress.com/2017/06/20/apache-axis-logging-of-soap-requestresponse-programmatically/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use handlers.

```
HandlerRegistry hr = locator.getHandlerRegistry();
List<HandlerInfo> handlerChain = hr.getHandlerChain((QName) locator.getPorts().next());

HandlerInfo hi = new HandlerInfo();
hi.setHandlerClass(MyHandlerClass.class);
handlerChain.add(hi);
```

For every handler class, you have to generate a `HandlerInfo` object. Register it on the chain and it should work. The `MyHandlerClass` should be a sub class of `javax.xml.rpc.handler.GenericHandler`. There you have to implement `handleResonse()` and/or `handleRequest()`. You can investigate the SOAPMessage (get it from the parameter `MessageContext` of the methods) and log things to your preferred logging framework.